Antivirus for one user in 2024
Can anyone recommend a good real-time antivirus solution for Ubuntu? I’ve come across plenty of suggestions online, but most of the websites seem to focus on business coverage rather than options suitable for home users. Any advice would be appreciated!
I have upgraded into 24.04.1 LTS.
Thank you

@kanehekili that looks like a good answer.

While ClamAV can scan Windows files and email sttachments, it is useless when applied to Linux. The Unix/Linux system design precludes viruses. We can still do dumb things like CloudFlare, but not Windows viruses.

@karel
Thank you for the suggested link. I read the link but most of the them are discontinued or offered only for businesses.

Someone should post a new answer there.

You will not need it

ClamTK (with ClamAV as base) is a de facto standard for those that deem it necessary to have such software.
Since it is Open Source, it should have moderate business coverage.
Do not download software from the "outside" - use Ubuntu's vast repository instead. Search there
